# How to add support for both React Native CLI and EXPO

Tags: react-native, expo, package.json, react-native-cli

It would be great if I could add support to debug React Native apps with the option to either run Expo or React Native CLI `npm run` within a single `package.json` file.

I.e `package.json` with:

```
  "scripts": {

    // expo commands
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject",

    // react-native commands
    "start-cli": "react-native start",
    "android-cli": "react-native run-android",
    "ios-cli": "react-native run-ios"
  },
```

In essence, I would like to generate a Expo project via:

```
expo init
```

And a React Native CLI project via:

```
react-native init
```

And consolidate the projects to support debugging either via Expo or React Native CLI.

**What is required to add React Native CLI support to the Expo project?**

Answer (score 0):

`React-native` and `Expo` are Not same but similar project systems.

And the reason this is impossible is that `React-native` basically creates the '`ios`' and '`android`' folders. and all of the Native code is unpacked into ios and android folders, and the App.js file is split into App.js and index.js, exposing the code that mounts the root React Native component.

But Expo However, Expo does not have `ios` and `android` folder.

There is an `ExpoKit` similar to the `React-native` project, but the set value is very different.